# Confluent Schema registry failed failed POST request

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

My local dev Kafka schema registry was working and I was able to POST the schema from my producer and get an ID back. I use auto-register=false, same as my production server. But I made an update to the schema, I added a string.

```
+                    {
+                        "name":"testkey",
+                        "type":{
+                            "type":"string",
+                            "avro.java.string":"String"
+                        },
+                        "doc":"test test test",
+                        "default":""
                     }
```

and the POST failed with a 404

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema:
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403

I have no idea why, the schema in my local code is the same as the one I posted to the server.

This is how I posted the schema:

jq '. | {schema: tojson}' ./mySchema.avsc | curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/subjects/mySchema/versions  -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d @-

Failure log:
[2021-03-05 10:39:14,690] INFO 172.19.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2021:10:39:14 +0000] "POST /subjects/mySchema?deleted=false HTTP/1.1" 404 49 62 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)

I am using confluent v5.1.2

Hope you can help advise me.

Comment: You need to show us that the subject for `mySchema` actually does exist

Comment: I got it to work when I called DELETE i.e. curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8081/subjects/mySchema and started again.  I think the issue was the first time the first schema was auto-registered and second was manually registered.  But second time around I manually registered both schemas.  in my env auto-register is disabled so I need to manually register.

Comment: this is the command use to register a schema: jq '. | {schema: tojson}' ./mySchema.avsc | curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/subjects/mySchema/versions  -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d @-

Comment: My point was that you'd have `-value` suffix for auto registered schemas, so without it, you should indeed expect a 404

Comment: if schema is changed we have to register is once with producerProps.put("auto.register.schemas", true);, for subsequent request we can set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

this is the command use to register a schema: jq '. | {schema: tojson}' ./mySchema.avsc | curl -X POST localhost:8081/subjects/mySchema/versions -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @- –
--> This command shared by mrmannione worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).